# Image Manipulation for QR code

Tags: python, jes, jython-2.5

I am currently doing an assignment for an introductory programming course in a language called Jython.

The assignment task I am working on says that my program needs to run a function that expands a QR code image to a size specified by the user, and to have a quiet zone around the image that is double what the size of the image size in pixels is. Then return the new image, with the QR code centered in the middle of the new image.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
def fixCodes1(moduleSize):
  smallPic = makePicture(getMediaPath("image1.png"))
  newPic = expand()
  height = getHeight(smallPic)
  width = getWidth(smallPic)
  moduleSizeFix = moduleSize - 1
  newPic = makeEmptyPicture((width*moduleSize)- moduleSizeFix, (height*moduleSize)-moduleSizeFix, white)
  sourceX = 0
  for targetX in range(0,0 + (width)*moduleSize):
    sourceY = 0
    for targetY in range(0,0 + (height*moduleSize)-1):
      color = getColor(getPixel(smallPic,int(sourceX),int(sourceY)))
      setColor(getPixel(newPic,targetX ,targetY),color)
      sourceY = sourceY + 0.5
    sourceX = sourceX + 0.5
  show(newPic)
  return newPic
```

When I run the above code it produces an image, however, I am given a error message that says:

> getPixel(picture,x,y): x (= 49) is less than 0 or bigger than the width (= 48)

I'm not sure how to go about fixing it, so any help would be greatly appreciated.
Also, I am a beginner coder, so if you could explain how you would go about fixing my program that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can Jython show you the *numerical value* of `moduleSize` that you are feeding into the next calculation? From its description, I don't believe for a second it is a number: "The *getPixels* function amasses a list of every single pixel in an image." That particular line looks random to me.

Comment: Rad Lexus you are right that moduleSize isn't a number,and Jython can't. I am a complete newbie when it comes to coding, and I misinterpreted what moduleSize was used for. It was my error.